# How can I estimate an first ODE with first order data, with the third order ODE form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, least-squares, pseudoinverse

Let's assume that we have the data $y(t), u(t)$ and it's from a first order ODE:

$$ \dot y(t) + a y(t) = b u(t) $$

But we have a ODE form at third order:
$$ \dddot y(t) + a \ddot y(t) + b \dot y(t) + cy(t) = d u(t) + d \dot u(t) $$

To estimate, I like to do that in this way:

$$ \dddot y(t) = -a \ddot y(t) - b \dot y(t) - cy(t) + d u(t) + d \dot u(t) $$

Then I set this on the form:

$$b = Ax$$

Where I solve $x$ with pseudo inverse:

$$x = A ^ {\dagger} b$$

Or I can set the equation like this:

$$ 0 = -a \dddot y(t) -b \ddot y(t) - c \dot y(t) - dy(t) + e u(t) + f \dot u(t) $$

And find the null space parameters.

The problem is that I try to curve fit first order ODE on a third order ODE form. Is there any way or algoritm to avoid this problem, because I don't know if my data is first order, second order or third order or higher.

How do I know if I should use first order, second order or third order ODE if I got input and output data $u(t), y(t)$ ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me, can you rephrase it? What exactly is given and what is not? Are you given $y,u$ and want to find corresponding coefficients? This is not at all uniquely determined, especially if you're not also given suitable initial data for derivatives of $y$.

Comment: Yes. I was given y and u and want to find the corresponding coefficients. But I don't know if I should use an third order ODE, second order ODE or first order ODE to fit on. I can compute the derivative of y.

Comment: But you cannot compute higher derivatives of $y$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Are you trying to find $c,d$ given $a,b,y(t),u(t)$, or what?

Comment: I'm going to find the parameters of an ODE and I got the input and output data. But I don't know if I should use first order ODE or second order ODE because the dynamisc of the data is unknow.

Comment: @ian yes. I can compute higher derivative with MATLAB ' S diff command.

Comment: @Daniel Mårtensson : Usually when they are several options, one solve the problem for each option one after the other and finally compare the respective results in order to select the best option. So, in your case, successively fit a first order ODE, then a second order ODE, then a third order ODE to your data. Compare the respective deviations according to some criteria of fitting and see which one is the more convenient

Comment: Like candidates ? @JJacquelin

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: @JJacquelin I talking about the same thing you talking about. Different ODE's where I try to find the best fit. Is there a way to for example have a A matrix as A = [-dx, -dx.^2, -sin(dx), -ddx, -ddx.^2, -sin(ddx), u, u.^2, sin(u)] then I try different columns in A to get the best if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

I try to minimize $ min _x ||Ax - b||$ where $A$ is my candidate functions of the derivatives and input $u$. The function glpk is a GNU Octave function for linear programming. Very fast!

```
A = [-dx, -dx.^2, -sin(dx), -ddx, -ddx.^2, -sin(ddx), u, sin(u)]; 
x = glpk([1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1], A, b)
```

$x$ will be for example $[3.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3, 0]$ for a first order data.